# How to upload a Custom service mix feature (features.xml) to internal Archiva maven reposistory

Tags: maven-2, apache-servicemix, archiva

I have a custom created service mix feature which is generally a features.xml file. Now i want to upload it to Archiva maven reposistory and use it to install it as a service mix feature. What will be the packaging type to refer to a file with .xml extention.

To install in service mix we use command features:addUrl mvn:a.b.c/abc/1.0/xml/features.

I am not able to make it work When i try to upload with a.b.c as group Id, abc as artifact Id, 1.0 as version and pom as packaging type. What am I supposed to do to make it work?

Comment: I would be interested how to do that via the archiva upload page, too.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following archetype to generate a karaf feature project, customize it and then build it with maven using 'mvn install'

```
mvn archetype:generate \
    -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.karaf.archetypes \
    -DarchetypeArtifactId=karaf-feature-archetype \
    -DarchetypeVersion=2.2.6 \
    -DgroupId=my.company \
    -DartifactId=my.company.feature \
    -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT \
    -Dpackage=my.company.package
```

for more info, see http://karaf.apache.org/manual/2.2.6/developers-guide/archetypes.html

Comment: Any idea how to do that via the archiva upload page without using maven?